# Retrieve Info from forum software with Android

Tags: android, web-scraping, forums

Say I pass a search Query to a forum board and I want to retrieve all the posts tags from the search on said forumboard.

How could I use android to parse all the posts?

I am lead to believe that I should utilize some form of API.

Can someone guide me down the right path?

I do not have a specific forumboard software in mind, if any forum softwares have good API please let me know.

Comment: Do you know what website you are trying to parse from? The [jsoup library] (https://jsoup.org/download) is fantastic for parsing html, but if the website offers an API that would be easier on performance and data.

Comment: hmm, this is all theory atm I do not have a website in mind. But I am looking at IPB's api. Here it is: https://invisionpower.com/developers/rest-api

I've been looking through multiple softwares documentation API and this is the only one that seems sensical...

Comment: Wait I thought you were searching other sites? Are you planning on making your own site and your own API? You can only get information from a successful response from the site the API is for, so say you use the Steam API, you can only get information that Steam allows you to get about users.

Comment: Yea sorry i should have clarified. It is a forumboard I am interested in making and searching specifically that forumboard. So I was gonna possibly use IPB for the forum software for my site, and then i wanna be able to get the results from a search query on my app. Hope im making sense to you, english is not my first language. 

Basically on my app the user makes a search, that search will look through my forum and then return specific aspects about the results to the user. It will cut out all the 'noise'

Comment: Okay good, much easier. In my opinion [swagger](http://swagger.io/) is much easier to use and CAN be free. Now you have a long way to go so I will make an answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so you are making a site that allows users to post things(?) and you can tag them. Just like here on Stack Overflow they allow you to tag your question and you can include that in the POST your website sends back to your server. Now you can send all sorts of information back to your servers including profile, question, tags, time of last update, etc; it really is limitless.

Now once you have that, if it is your own site you can then incorporate the Swagger API or whatever API you want, or you can hook your android app directly to the server and implement the same search features there as on the website. Once you have that determined, if you want to use an API for your app then you will need to look at AsyncTask for android. This little handy task can crawl the website in the background and return whatever you want, including API information if that is what you want.

I know this answer is broad but your question is broad, you have to start from the ground up and it can be challenging but remember that in order to get good at something it takes time, and if this is something you really want to do then it's not time wasted.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. Its just that i am a bit troubled with where to begin. I understand Asynctask but my issue atm is how do I send the search request to the server(my forum?) and then return the tags from that search result?

Comment: Well unfortunately you need a server to test on... So I recommend this one [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) It is a test server and very very easy to use especially with android. There isn't a lot of room in here to answer so I will say to look at this app I made to show how to use API information [Steam Integration](https://github.com/kanoka42/Steam-Integration-For-Android). You really don't need to look at anything other than the MainFragment. That shows you how AsyncTask works!

Comment: AsyncTask is so low-level. Why not any other HTTP library?

Comment: I said to use it here because it is native. I know he could use another library such as OkHTTP, but thats not really learning how to beat the problem at hand if you're new. At least from my perspective.